# Поиск слов вне скобок

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Подскажите как сделать дальше. Сделал такое: `([А-Я]([а-я]+))`. Оно находит все слова с заглавными буквами.

К этому нужно еще сделать что бы слово в скобках не находилось. Как такое сделать?

Пример предложения:
`Недорогой отдых в Сочи(Россия), цены 2018`

Comment: А если будет `Недорогой отдых в Сочи(в России, доступный каждому), цены 2018`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

```
((?<=[^(])|^)[А-Я][а-я]+((?=[^)])|$)
```

Comment: тоже работает..

Answer (score 1):

```
([А-Я][а-я]+)(?=\s)|([А-Я][а-я]+)(?=\()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Этот вариант не учитывает открывающую скобку (не знаю на сколько это критично автору) и не учитывает что слово может стоять в конце строки. Пример: `Город Сочи`. Ну и избыточность: 2 раза входит подпаттерн `([А-Я][а-я]+)`